# Java applet run from web page cannot be Run

Tags: java, applet

Hello I Create a Java applet and run successfully (when press button the notepad Run) form netbeans but when run the Application from web page the notpad.exe cannot be run

Comment: `notepad.exe` are you trying to start native programs from the applet - then you need the permissions for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a Java applet run by default in a "sandbox" that means, it can't access to the user's file system and program.
When you try it, in your netbean, it's different because the "sandbox" isn't apply.

[What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not allowed for java applets to run notepad on user's computer ?

Comment: No when run the application from netbeans the notepad is run successfully but when make a build application and run the application from outside the netbeans the notepad doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

You have to get applet signed, so that you can access Native programs(.exe). Like said above, Currently its working in sandbox mode. sign the applet and it will work